# Swift: Why can I pass info from one IBAction to another, but not to a function

Tags: swift, function, global, ibaction

I am trying to get the values for splitValue and tipPercent into the getSettings() at the bottom.  Why can I get the values for both of those in the IBAction calculatePressed, but when I try to get the values into the function the value is nil.  I am sooo confused.  Thank you for the help!

```
@IBOutlet weak var billTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var zeroPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tenPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var twentyPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var splitNumberLabel: UILabel!

var tipChosen = ""
var totalPerPerson = ""
var tipPercent = ""
var splitValue = ""

@IBAction func tipChanged(_ sender: UIButton) {
    tipPercent = sender.currentTitle!

    if sender.isSelected == true {
        return
    }

    zeroPctButton.isSelected = false
    tenPctButton.isSelected = false
    twentyPctButton.isSelected = false
    sender.isSelected = true

    if sender.currentTitle == "0%" {
        tipChosen = "0.00"
    } else if sender.currentTitle == "10%" {
        tipChosen = "0.10"
    } else if sender.currentTitle == "20%" {
        tipChosen = "0.20"
    }

    billTextField.endEditing(true)
}

@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    splitValue = String(Int(sender.value))
    splitNumberLabel.text = String(Int(sender.value))

}

@IBAction func calculatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let bill = Float(billTextField.text!)!
    let tip = Float(tipChosen)!
    let tax = bill * tip
    let splitNumber = Float(splitNumberLabel.text!)
    let total = (bill + tax) / Float(splitNumber!)
    totalPerPerson = "$\(String(format: "%.2f", total))"

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTotal", sender: self)
}
func getSettings() -> String {
    return "Split between \(splitValue) people, with a \(tipPercent) tip."
}
```

Comment: You are not accessing splitValue and tipPercent in calculatePressed so your claim is not really correct. Also since the properties are all initialised to "" I don't really see how they can be nil. It would help if you posted the code for `getSettings` that is causing the problem. Another note, if you are doing calculations using your properties I would suggest making them into numbers like int or double and not text.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "your claim is not really correct"?  I have tried printing, one at a time, the two properties by themselves and it prints nil.

Comment: I meant you are not accessing either of them in the function `calculatePressed` but yet you say you can get the values there. This is not so important, the important thing is why they have become nil. You should debug your code or use print statements where you are assigning values to them.

Comment: Oh, got it.  All of the info passes with no problem, except to that function.  I have done all of the printing statements and they all check.  I have tried many ways to pass the info to that function and they all come back nil.

Comment: Where do you call it from?

Comment: The getSettings() I call from another view controller, but when I test, I test it just to get it to print without passing the info to the other controller.  Also, I am getting an error that tipChosen inside calculatePressed is nil (like you said), but it's still working for whatever reason. The string without variables passes to 2nd view controller with no issues.

Comment: Maybe you should do it the other way around and have the same properties in your other vier controller and assign the values in `prepare(for: segue)`

Comment: OOh, ok.  I will try that and let you know.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry it took me a bit, but I finally think I understand what I did.

class CalculatorViewController: UIViewController {

```
var tip = 0.0
var finalBill = ""
var split = 2

@IBOutlet weak var billTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var zeroPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tenPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var twentyPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var splitNumberLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func tipChanged(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected == false {
        sender.isSelected = false
    } else if sender.isSelected == true {
        sender.isSelected = true
    }

    zeroPctButton.isSelected = false
    tenPctButton.isSelected = false
    twentyPctButton.isSelected = false
    sender.isSelected = true

    billTextField.endEditing(true)
}

@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {

    splitNumberLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description

}

@IBAction func calculatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if zeroPctButton.isSelected == true {
        tip = 0.0
    } else if tenPctButton.isSelected == true {
        tip = 0.1
    } else if twentyPctButton.isSelected == true {
        tip = 0.2
    }
    print(tip)
    let bill = Double(billTextField.text!)
    split = Int(Double(splitNumberLabel.text!)!)

    if billTextField.text != "" {
        let billWithTip = (bill! * tip) + bill!
        let billWithTipSplit = billWithTip / Double(split)
        finalBill = String(format: "%.2f", billWithTipSplit)
        print(billWithTip)
    }

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "getResults", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "getResults" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ResultsViewController

        destinationVC.finalBill = finalBill
        destinationVC.split = split
        destinationVC.tip = tip

    }
}
```

}

class ResultsViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var settingsLabel: UILabel!

var tip = 0.0
var split = 2
var finalBill = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    totalLabel.text = "$\(finalBill)"
    settingsLabel.text = "Split between \(Int(split)) people, with a \(Int(tip * 100))% tip"
}

@IBAction func recalculatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

}

I did what you suggested with the string and some minor calculations on the second view controller, changed the values of a few declared properties and got rid of the getSettings(). I was under the impression that I couldn't pass data without a return value from a function.  Thank you for the help!